# List users without softdeletes

Tags: laravel, middleware, soft-delete

I have implemented softdeleteds and work well. Problem is when I delete a user and list them again users deleted appear again.

I know softdeletes works because when I execute delete() method update_at and delete_at fields change.

This is my controller:

```
public function deleteUser($user_id)
{
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    $policies = Policy::where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
    foreach ($policies as $policy) {
      $policy->user_id = 0;
      $policy->save();
      }
    $user->delete();
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

When I redirect to home (listing users) appear the delete (soft) user again

May be is problem about Middleware admin because yesterday before this middlewae works well. May be middleware avoid use delete() method correctly?

If I put dd($user_id) after $user->delete() still show id user...I dont know

Any help please?

Comment: Isn't `$user_id` a independent value? `dd($user_id);` returning the value based on what you passed to the method, not related to `$user`.

Comment: did you check your db `deleted_at` changes after the `$user->delete();` is called?

Comment: Do you have the `SoftDeletes` trait on the User model?

Comment: show us the code for listing the users. @DigitalDrifter I would assume SoftDeletes trait is there since deleted_at is updated. if you use query builder to get the users they will still show up